# Cartoon from the 80's or early 90's with 3 robot suits

Tags: story-identification, tv, anime, cartoon, mecha

This was a cartoon TV show from the 80's or early 90's.

There were 3 different sets of robotic suits one small, one medium and a large one. The small one would go inside the medium one, and then the medium would go inside the larger one. I believe one of the suits had a football (NFL) as a "weapon".

What was the show called?

Comment: UFO Diapolon? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HgJR9oSm6RU

Comment: Gordian Warrior? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EhTuM_uFok

Answer (score 1):

This could be [*Gordian Warrior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordian_Warrior) (as suggested by Valorum):

- it originally aired in Japan from 1979 to 1981, and was later dubbed and aired in other countries
- the protagonist pilots three robots, which assemble Matryoshka-style

> The pilot Daigo Otaki controls a small almost human-sized robot container named Protteser. Each time Protteser is in trouble, he jumps into the next biggest robot container named Delinger. Then finally the largest container is Garbin.
>   <sub>(quote from Wikipedia)</sub>

- the smaller robot is American football-themed, with a helmet and a weaponized oval-shaped football

[image: image of the robots]
<sub>(image from [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordian))</sub>